# Finding number of primes of the form $1010\ldots 101$ (in base 10)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

How many primes among the positive integers, written as usual in the
base $10$, are such that their digits are alternating $1$’s and $0$’s, beginning
and ending with $1$?

Comment: (Equivalently, these are the numbers of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n100^k$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only answer is $101$

Proof:

Let $T_n$ be the number based on the number of ones. Then
$$
T_0 = 0, T_1 = 1, T_2=101, T_3 = 10101 ~~~\text{etc}
$$
Note that
$$
T_{n+1} = 100 T_n + 1
$$
and hence
$$
T_n =\frac{100^n-1}{99}
$$
We can write $T_n$ as
$$
T_n = \frac{\left(10^n\right)^2-1}{99} = \frac{(10^n-1)\,(10^n+1)}{99}$$

Thus the $T_n$ is composite except when $10^n-1 = 99$, i.e when $n=2$.

**Hence the only prime is $101$**